# How do I use regex to find FS.File on FS.Collection in meteor

Tags: meteor

How do I use regex to find FS.File on FS.Collection in meteor. My code is as follows and it is not working

```
partOfFileName = "*User_" + clickedResellerId + "_*";
var imgs = Images.find({fileName:{$regex:partOfFileName}});
//var imgs = Images.find();
return imgs // Where Images is an FS.Collection instance
```

In place of fileName I've also tried name and it is not working either. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your regex is valid. Did you perhaps mean the following?

```
partOfFileName = ".*User_" + clickedResellerId + "_.*";
```

Please note that POSIX wildcard notation is different from regular expressions. in Regular expressions the `*` operators indicates repetition of the preceding operator (in my case a `.`, i.e., anything). A `*` by itself has no meaning, and it doesn't mean "anything" like in POSIX.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks once again Christian. So it turns out I had to put original.name or copies.images.name in place of fileName.